# How to push files to GitHub using Dart

Tags: git, github, dart, github-api

I have a Dart server side project I would like to maintain on GitHub. Experimented briefly with the 2 pub packages "git" & "github".  Also considered using Process.Run for the typical batch commands:

```sh
cd project_directory
git init
git add .
git commit -m "your_commit_message"
git remote add origin https://github.com/[your_user_name]/[repo_name]
git push origin master
```

Is there a standard implementation for Dart? Are Devs rolling their own with Process.Run?
It would be great to find a simple straight forward documented HeloWorld type example pushing to GitHub.
Any ideas or examples much appreciated!

Comment: I wouldn't be afraid to write a shell script that you call via Process.run(). Nothing wrong with that. :)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i ended up doing. I'll post it for others.

Answer (score 2):

The Chrome Dev Editor team have written a native Git client in Dart (I presume it's [in here](https://github.com/dart-lang/chromedeveditor/tree/924bd8844a05aedaa02dfdd3fa5fe38ad1e6e394/ide/web/lib/git)). It's not complete and I don't know how easily you can use it (it's not a pub package; and I don't know if it ever will be); but it's definitely where I'd start if I was trying to interact with Git.

Comment: Thanks, code looks like a great source for ideas and learning!

Answer (score 1):

Decided to go "old school" for now with Windows command file. Posting here incase others are interested:

```sh
:: --------------------------------------------
:: PUBLISH TO GITHUB
:: dxConsole:Dart Console Library for Windows(32/64bit Native Extension)
:: --------------------------------------------
mode con:cols=100 lines=200

setlocal

:: --------------------------------------------
:: Initialize environment variables
:: --------------------------------------------
set ERRORMSG=
:: <<< Set Paths  >>>
set PATH-GITLOCALREPRO=%TMP%\dxConsole
set PATH-GITHUBDXCONSOLE=[https://github.com/osstekz/dxConsole][1]
set PATH-DXCONSOLEPROJECTPATH=C:\Users\OSSDevYorgi\DartProjects\libraries\native-ext\dxConsole\

:: <<< remove the temp directory >>>
rmdir /s /q %PATH-GITLOCALREPRO%\
:: <<< make temp GitRepro sub folders >>>
mkdir %PATH-GITLOCALREPRO%\
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0  goto ERRORHANDLER

:: --------------------------------------------
:: <<< Init/clone local repository >>>
:: --------------------------------------------
::go into folder.. 
cd %PATH-GITLOCALREPRO%
::if folder is empty, then clone repro
git clone %PATH-GITHUBDXCONSOLE% .
::else
::git init
::git remote add origin %PATH-GITHUBDXCONSOLE%
::git config user.name "<your user name>"
::git fetch
::git checkout -t origin/master

if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0  goto ERRORHANDLER

:: --------------------------------------------
:: <<< Copy local project files to local git repository >>>
:: --------------------------------------------
:: <<< Set Dart project path >>>
cd %PATH-DXCONSOLEPROJECTPATH%

:: <<< Copy example folder >>>
rmdir /s /q %PATH-GITLOCALREPRO%\example\
xcopy /Y example\dxConsoledemo_*.* %PATH-GITLOCALREPRO%\example\
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0  goto ERRORHANDLER
:: <<< Copy lib folder >>>
rmdir /s /q %PATH-GITLOCALREPRO%\lib\
xcopy /Y /e lib\*.* %PATH-GITLOCALREPRO%\lib\
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0  goto ERRORHANDLER
:: <<< Copy bin folder >>>
rmdir /s /q %PATH-GITLOCALREPRO%\bin\
xcopy /Y git\bin\dxConsole_win*.dll %PATH-GITLOCALREPRO%\bin\
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0  goto ERRORHANDLER
:: <<< Copy root items >>>
copy git\gitattributes.txt %PATH-GITLOCALREPRO%\.gitattributes
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0  goto ERRORHANDLER
copy git\gitignore.txt %PATH-GITLOCALREPRO%\.gitignore
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0  goto ERRORHANDLER
copy git\license.txt* %PATH-GITLOCALREPRO%\LICENSE
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0  goto ERRORHANDLER
copy git\README.md %PATH-GITLOCALREPRO%\README.md
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0  goto ERRORHANDLER
copy pubspec.yaml %PATH-GITLOCALREPRO%\
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0  goto ERRORHANDLER

:: <<< Update Github >>>
cd %PATH-GITLOCALREPRO%

git add .
git commit -m "v0.8.0"
::git commit -a 
git push origin master

@echo.
@echo -----------------------------------------
@echo SUCCESS:GOOD JOB
@echo -----------------------------------------
@echo.
goto :exit
:: --------------------------------------------
:: SUBROUTINE:ERRORHANDLER
:: --------------------------------------------
:ERRORHANDLER
@echo.
@echo -----------------------------------------
@echo ERROR:%ERRORMSG%
@echo -----------------------------------------
@echo.
pause
:: --------------------------------------------
:: END OF JOB
:: --------------------------------------------
:exit
::%temp%\dxConsole.log
::set
:exit1
::pause
```

Comment: I haven't used it myself yet but with this package it should be easy to write this in Dart https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/git

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on Danny's reply see the section "Git workflow" in the [GettingStarted.md](https://github.com/dart-lang/chromedeveditor/blob/924bd8844a05aedaa02dfdd3fa5fe38ad1e6e394/doc/GettingStarted.md) for the CDE project.

The CDE is in the Chrome Store. After you clone a git project into the CDE, you can right-click on files to commit changes, among other git functions.

Comment: @Danny,@user104531: Thank you for the links. CDE's git library is extraordinary work! Would love to see it as a pub package.